# Show "trailing zeros" from WooCommerce just on the backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce

I am using the code bellow to hide the ".00" from the prices on WooCommerce. That it works good, although I have to show the ".00" of the prices on the backend/admin panel, so the generated Invoice PDFs show the full price with ".00".

Here is the code most known:

```
/**
 * Trim zeros in price decimals
 **/
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```

I would like to run this snippet just on the front-end.

Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [is_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) - Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page.

```php
// Default = false
function filter_woocommerce_price_trim_zeros( $trim ) {
    // True if inside WordPress administration interface, false otherwise.
    // if NOT true = false
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $trim = true;
    }

    return $trim;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', 'filter_woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help. Yesterday on Slack I've got that solution, but I realized on the emails the prices are without ".00". Do you know how to have the possibility for the emails as well? 

if ( ! is_admin() || is_email() ) { }